# tcl find and replace in file

Tags: replace, find, tcl

I need help with tcl. I have a text file with the following format:

```
Main = 1
Bgp = 0
Backup = 1
```

I need to increment the integer value by 1 for each item, for example replacing `Main = 1` with `Main = 2`, and so on.

Comment: what have you tried? This is a pretty basic program that you should be able to do after working through a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

(Changed my answer: I was a little irritable, sorry.)

If the text to be processed is in a variable called `data`, one can turn the text into a list of words and go through them three at a time like this:

```
set result ""
foreach {keyword op value} [split [string trim $data]] {
    append result "$keyword $op [incr value]\n"
}
```

In this case, each keyword (*Main, Bgp, Backup, ...*) ends up inside the loop variable `keyword`, each equals sign (or whatever is in the second position) ends up inside the loop variable `op`, and each value to be incremented ends up inside `value`.

(When splitting, it's typically a good idea to trim off white-space at the beginning and end of the text first: otherwise one can get empty "ghost" elements. Hence: `split [string trim $data]`)

We can read the data from the file "datafile" like this:

```
set f [open datafile r+]
set data [read $f]
```

Note that we use `r+` to be able to both read from and write to the file.

Once we have processed the data, we can write it back at the beginning of the file like this:

```
seek $f 0
puts -nonewline $f $result
close $f
```

or possibly like this, which means we didn't have to open the file with `r+`:

```
close $f
set f [open datafile w]
puts -nonewline $f $result
close $f
```

Putting it together:

```
set f [open datafile r+]
set data [read $f]
set result ""
foreach {keyword op value} [split [string trim $data]] {
    append result "$keyword $op [incr value]\n"
}
seek $f 0
puts -nonewline $f $result
close $f
```

This procedure can also be simplified a bit using the standard package `fileutil`, which can take care of the file opening, closing, reading, and writing for us.

First, we put the processing in a procedure:

```
proc process data {
    foreach {keyword = value} [split [string trim $data]] {
        append result "$keyword ${=} [incr value]\n"
    }
    return $result
}
```

Then we can just ask ask `updateInPlace` to update the contents of the file with new contents processed by `process`.

```
package require fileutil

::fileutil::updateInPlace datafile process
```

And that's it.

Documentation:
[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[seek](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/seek.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
# read the data
set f [open file]
set data [read -nonewline $f]
close $f

# increment the numbers
regsub -all {=\s*(\d+)\s*$} $data {= [expr {\1 + 1}]} new
set new [subst -novariables -nobacklashes $new]

# write the data
set f [open file w]
puts $f $new
close $f
```

That regsub command will replace `Main = 1` with `Main = [expr {1 + 1}]`, and then the subst command actually invokes the expr command to compute the new value